# When player move outside world walls he should move to opposite wall

Tags: actionscript-3

How do i make that if player moves outside the left world wall it should appear at right wall just like the picture shows: http://prntscr.com/va69f

Answer (score 2):

You might use a condition like this:

```
var worldWidth:int = rightWall.x - leftWall.x;
if (newX < leftWall.x)
{
    newX += worldWidth;
}
else if (newX > rightWall.x)
{
    newX -= worldWidth;
}
```

This solution has the advantage to work even if your left wall is not at position 0.
It'll also work if the player moves outside the world either on the left or the right side (as your question is not consistent with the picture you linked).

Answer (score 0):

You could use modulo arithmetic. Say the size of the world is `width` and the player moves `distance`, you could do:

```
new_x = (old_x + distance) % width;
```

if it goes over the width of the world, its new x position will be at the beginning